# Drag & drop HTML5 file upload into the media library?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Has anyone seen a drag&drop plugin for files into the media library for WP? Would be very interested with such a plugin.

**Edit** - Seems like Google will [sponsor this project](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/google/gsoc2011/jacobwg/21001) on GSoC 2011

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you're looking for in a bit more detail?  I'm not sure what HTML5 has to do with a drag-drop plug-in ... or whether you want this for file uploads or management of files already on the site ...

Comment: It's the new File API and the Drag & Drop API. Here is a demo http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/ Also, it's now supported in Gmail for file attachments with modern browsers which support html5

Comment: I've seen drag and drop as well as select multiple files via a button in action now. It's something very useful for browsers on systems that do not have flash installed. It needs that you have javascript enabled though. It's just something nice to have, as it prevents the browser from loading a plugin if this replaces the swf uploader.

Comment: Just some more links: http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload
http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/fileapi

Comment: And another one: http://ajaxian.com/archives/drag-and-drop-file-uploads-in-gmail-using-just-the-specs

Comment: It seems like Google will sponsor this for the GSoC 2011. Check out this link: http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/google/gsoc2011/jacobwg/21001

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this idea is being addressed in trac:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13054

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a plugin, but it works only with Firefox:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-pro-wordpress-image-media-management-and-resizing-done-right/

And another one which works with all browsers:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wplupload/